# On hover rotate image in div

Tags: jquery, image, rotation

Im not sure what to search for regarding my problem. So Im going to describe it here with text an one image.

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAWxy.png

The blue boxes are the one which are in focus in the div for the moment. The green on the left have been in focus earlier. The green to the right is going to enter the div once the user hover on the right corner of the div. The red line representing the div.

So what I want to do is to show a couple of images in one div and when the user is hovering over the right side of the div the images should rotate. I also want to make the image start over so there should be no "end" when all the images have been shown. It should loop.

What should I search on to find information getting me in the right direction? I want to do this with jQuery.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ please ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want a standard carousel, with next and previous being triggered by mouseover. Most carousels will probably be able to achieve this.

So if your question is what to search for, start with "jQuery carousel".